# Инициализация фигурными скобками и круглыми

Tags: c++, классы, инициализация

Читаю книгу и в ней есть пример класса, который использует идиому RAII для работы с потоками. Вот код

```
class thread_guard {
    thread& t;
public:
    explicit thread_guard(thread& _t) : t(_t){}
    ~thread_guard() {
        if (t.joinable())
            t.join();
 }
    thread_guard(thread_guard const&) = delete;
    thread_guard& operator=(thread_guard const&) = delete;
};

void f(int i, std::string const& s) {
    cout << s << " " << i << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    thread thr1(f, 2, "test");
    thread_guard{ thr1 };

}
```

Мой вопрос состоит в том, что если в функции `int main` в строке содержащим операцию

```
thread_guard{ thr1 };
```

вместо фигурных скобок использовать круглые, то код не компилируется. Я не могу понять чем они в данном моменте отличаются. Скотт Майерс об этом не писал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всякий раз когда в языке С++ возникает неоднозначность между *объявлением* и *выражением* - т.е. в ситуациях, когда конструкция может быть и синтаксически правильным объявлением, и синтаксически правильным выражением - язык обязан трактовать конструкцию как объявление.

Согласно этому правилу, вариант `thread_guard( thr1 );` является объявлением переменной `thr1` с лишними скобками вокруг имени переменной. Синтаксис объявления не запрещает такие скобки

```
int (i) = 42; // Корректное объявление
```

При желании, вы можете намеренно "испортить" синтаксис объявления так

```
(void) thread_guard( thr1 );
```

или так

```
0, thread_guard( thr1 );
```

и компилятор будет вынужден трактовать этот код как выражение, т.е. он станет эквивалентен исходному варианту с `{}`.

Собственно, прелесть униформной инициализации через `{}` как раз и состоит во многом в отсутствии таких неоднозначностей.

---

Меня удивляет поведение GCC вот в таком варианте

```
thread_guard( thr1 ), 0;
```

GCC отказывается это компилировать, в то время как Clang воспринимает и этот вариант как выражение.

Comment: Грамматика C++ это вообще дурдом, посмотрите [короткое видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsG95Y-C14k), если ещё не видели. Это довольно забавно.

Answer (score 2):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то

```
thread_guard(thr1);
```

компилятор воспринимает как объявление переменной `thr1` типа `thread_guard`, а строкой выше такая переменная уже была объявлена иначе. Вот если бы вы написали, скажем,

```
thread_guard tg(thr1);
```

явно указав переменную - то это бы было объявление переменной `tg`, инициализируемой `thr1`, и код бы спокойно работал.

С фигурными скобками прочесть это иначе как инициализацию нельзя, и код состоит в создании [безымянного] объекта типа `thread_guard`, инициализированного ссылкой `thr1`.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*